# Replacing </div> with <\/div>

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, underscore.js

I'm attempting to replicate the kind of data passed in an alternate sample of some code.  I am attempting to recreate a NodeJS implementation based on C# and PHP samples.

The 'template' data contains html data in a string like:

```
    <div>10<\/div>
```

So I've been attempting to use the JavaScript .replace() function to accomplish this.

```
    temp = temp.replace(/<\//g, "<\/");
    //outputs: </div>
```

and

```
    temp = temp.replace(/<\//g, "<\\/");
    //outputs: <\\/div>
```

I can't seem to accomplish the middleground to replicate the data in the samples.

Comment: You're probably seeing escaped output.  How are you looking at the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are: `\/` for `/`, `g` for search all places, `\\` for `\`

```js
alert('<div>10</div>'.replace(/<\//g, '<\\/'))
```

Hope this helps.